# .NET COM Interop Method Signature

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, com-interop

What interop signature would you use for the following COM method? I am interested particularly in the final two parameters, and whether to try to use `MarshalAs` with a `SizeParamIndex` or not.

```
HRESULT GetOutputSetting(
  DWORD    dwOutputNum,
  LPCWSTR  pszName,
  WMT_ATTR_DATATYPE*  pType,
  BYTE*    pValue,
  WORD*    pcbLength
);
```

Documentation states:

> **pValue** [out]  Pointer to a byte buffer containing the value. Pass NULL
>   to retrieve the length of the buffer
>   required.
>
> **pcbLength** [in, out]  On input, pointer to a variable containing the
>   length of pValue. On output, the
>   variable contains the number of bytes
>   in pValue used.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [PInvoke Signature Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/clrinterop/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14120). It's rather useful for getting marshaling right when performing platform interops. It quite possibly won't cover your particular problem, but you may find a comparable one that gives you the information you seek.

Comment: I have. Its a nice tool, but it doesn't know what to do with things like this. It assumes that pValue is a single byte.

Comment: It's forced to assume byte* because there is no other data.  You can add SAL annotations to give it enough context to generate the appropriate invocation.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the SizeParamIndex, because your scenario is exactly the one this feature is for: To specify the length of a variable sized array.

So the last to parameters would be in C# signature:

```
byte[] pValue,
ref ushort pcbLength
```

The byte-Array is passed without *ref*, because the array corresponds to a pointer in native code.
If you pass NULL (or null in C#) for pValue in order to retrieve the size of the buffer needed. That means also that the caller has to allocate the byte-Array.
The parameter pcbLength is passed by *ref*, because it is used as an in/out-parameter.

Comment: ref for pValue is incorrect.  If you look at the native signature there is only a single level of indirection (one pointer).  Having an array + ref = 2 levels of indirection.

Comment: You are right, JaredPar. Thanks! I've edited my original answer to incorporate your comment,